# Limit on how much data can be returned by Json Post?

Tags: asp.net, security, json, getjson

I have [read](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx) that you should not use get json for retrieving sensitive data and you should instead use json post.

I am wondering though what is the limit you can send back. I know with http post there is a limited(I forgot how much).

Does the same limit apply to json post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use JSON over an unencrypted http connection, it doesn't really matter if it's a POST or a GET, your data will be sent in clear text and anyone with a [network sniffer](http://www.wireshark.org/) will be able to read the sensitive data.

Comment: I just read the article that you linked in your question (http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx) , and the exploit described by the article is quite interessting. I think that the exploit would work even if the communication is encrypted with HTTPS. I guess it's better to follow the advice and use POST (over https of course) to send sensitive data using json.

Comment: Ya but I am still wondering is their a limit on how much can be sent back if you use POST instead?

Comment: No, you should not have any limit.

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit to the data you can route as part of a GET or a POST.  However, I would suggest that whomever said not to use GET for sensitive data is misleading you.  In particular,

- You can certainly encrypt the data (i.e., HTTPS GET) so that it cannot be viewed by others.
- You can also specify cache control headers to prevent it from being cached.

Both should eliminate any concerns about sensitivity.  Furthermore, this is not a JSON-specific thing.  REST-based access to Web services can transmit the data in a number of formats (JSON and XML just happen to be the most popular).